# I just want to know the main purpose of the below file

Tags: gitlab

I just want to know the main purpose of ".gitlab-ci.yml" file. Can some one help me with answering this question?

Answer (score 2):

The ".gitlab-ci.yml" file serves as a configuration set for GitLab CI or CD. Just like CircleCI or Jenkins, where you need a config.yml file, the YML file contains all the deployment instructions instead of inserting the Git commands manually. Kind of like a script that executes all the commands that you would normally write in a notepad to remember.

If you want more information, you can read the documentation regarding GitLab CI/CD at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/quick_start/.